# Is SHA-Encryption already decrypted?

Tags: encryption, sha1, sha256, sha, sha512

I went here http://shadecrypt.com/home and typed some sha results (encrpted already by sha512) and it gives back the real word.

Is it already decrypted?

Comment: its an online rainbow table, very useful...

Comment: is it good that i posted it here? :O

Comment: probably not the best place as your question is not specific, but i liked the link...

Comment: as per your comment, i researched the rainbow table and it says it is just a precomputed has . so probably it's just a matching algo not a decryptor :)

Comment: SHA* isn't encryption, they are Hash algorithms. A rainbow table is a reverse lookup table (based on small words or phrases) so it may look like a decryption. The site calls it that.

Comment: They store there own "encrypted" values, to evaluate this you need to feed it hashes from another source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically, it is incorrect to use the word "decryption" when talking about hash functions; "reversing" is a slightly better term.

The site you're linking to is basically an online [Rainbow table](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Rainbow_table) and there's no harm in linking to it: one could trivially (sans storage costs) produce hash values for all `[A-Za-z0-9]*` character combinations and end up with basically the same result.

Speaking of SHA-1, Bruce Schneier considers it [broken](https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2005/02/sha1_broken.html).

Comment: While SHA-1 is generally a very poor choice it is not broken for **all** uses. It is broken for digital signatures but not for HMAC as examples.